# How to replace string with string in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need to replace the first substring in a string with a new string.

For example:

```
import string
message = 'First part' + ';' + 'Second part'
m='101.0.0.1'
message[0]=str.replace (message[0],message[0],m)
print (message)
```

**I want to get an answer of "101.0.0.1;Second part"**

but I am getting the following error:

> 'str' object does not support item assignment.

Can anybody help me? How I can get an answer like "101.0.0.1; Second part"?

Comment: @StephenRauch (hey do notifications work in this case?) I reopened this because OP's misunderstanding goes deeper than how replacing strings works.

Comment: @AlexHall Really?  We need another answer explaining immutability?

Comment: @StephenRauch no, like I said, OP needs several things explained, particularly their misunderstanding of `message[0]`.

Comment: @StephenRauch I disagree that a question should only ever be answered if it has long term value to other visitors. OP needed help. I gave it. I was not going to let OP struggle for hours wondering why, say, `message = str.replace (message[0],message[0],m)` or `message = message.replace(message[0],m)` didn't work, as that is probably as far as the duplicates would have helped them. I was not going to squeeze the information in my answer below into a comment. If you want those duplicate links here, close the question or put them in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
message = 'First part' + ';' + 'Second part'
```

Is exactly equivalent to:

```
message = 'First part; Second part'
```

The `+` is just combining the strings together into one. It is not going to make Python remember each part separately so that `message[0]` is `'First part'`. `message[0]` is just the first character of the string, so it's `'F'`.

The best you can do is:

```
message = 'First part; Second part'
m='101.0.0.1'
message = message.replace('First part', m)
print(message)
```

The `import string` is not needed at all and calling the method directly on `str` is not something you want to do.

Comment: @ Alex hall Thanks 
but my problem is still same. I already did which you send me as ans.
but now I am sending you small portion program of server and client on which i am trying to replace.I am sending T_message from cleint to sever using socket 
Client side 
T_message='req_status' + ";" + '(20,30)' + ";" + '172.168.1.1 + ";" + '45j'
T_message_bytes= bytes(T_message,'utf-8')
Server side
 data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
 data1=data.split(';')
 ip='101.2.2.2'
 Old-ip=data[2]
 data12=data1.replace(Old-ip,ip)
 Now Please help me how i can replace '172.168.1.1' with new ip '101.2.2.2'

Comment: @irfanyounus (1) don't put `-` in a variable name, as in `Old-ip`, because that's the subtraction operator (2) `data1` is a list and doesn't have a replace method, use the string, i.e. `data12 = data.replace(...)`.